# Can't align buttons with horizontal form (not inline) (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the code below I have 2 buttons and 3 labeled inputs. I want the buttons aligned with the inputs, but they are aligned with the labels. I tried inline forms, but having the labels on the side won't do.

What's the best option to accomplish this without breaking bootstrap too much?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</script>

<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can change the top attribute for the two buttons and make them align to the input elements. But then again it depends on how big your labels are going to be

Comment: If your labels are going to be always short. Then you can use top on the btns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap and you might not want to customize CSS too much unless you really know what you are doing.

Therefore, try to have the same structure then you will get the same result, add `<label>&nbsp;</label>` to those button as a placeholder, so they will behavior the same as screen changes.

Also add `form-control` to the submit button and let bootstrap deal with it :D

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control">Filter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Panque the height/margin are controlled by bootstrap, unless you add the same style to those buttons. best way to follow it is to use the same structure and style

Comment: Had some issues with the + button but solved it by adding form-control to it. Thanks, I really liked this solution.

Comment: Really smart one! Thx

Answer (score 2):

Quickest (and not a little dirty) way I can think of doing this to fit with Bootstrap would be to introduce placeholder labels, then hiding them.  Note however that this is very fragile as it stands - if the layout is allowed to get too compressed width-wise (or if label text is allowed to wrap), misalignment will still occur:

```css
.invisible-label {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
      <label class="invisible-label">&nbsp;</label>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <label>Text Input</label>
      <input class="form-control">
      <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
      <label class="invisible-label">&nbsp;</label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying `display:inline-block` to the `label` and the `input` should allow them to flow onto the same line, but may simply require `display:inline`

Comment: Alright! Just tracked down the issue. First, you are missing the closing tag for your `row` div. Second, the `form-control` class applies a `display:block` to the input that you don't need. After removing `form-control` and applying `display:inline-block` everything works as expected

Comment: Sorry, I'm a begginer, where should I apply display:inline-block?

Comment: You're going to want to do it in your css styles! Something like this: `label {display:inline-block;}` and `input {display: inline-block;}`, you can put these in between `<style></style>` at the top of your page, just below the link that includes bootstrap's css

Comment: I must be missing something obvious, the labels are still on the left side instead of above. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: No no, I misunderstood your question! I thought you were trying to have the input and the label on the same line, as well as the button. Using a blank label as a spacer is indeed the best way to achieve this. And the other answer is correct, you wouldn't want to entirely remove `form-control`! Good luck.