# aligning the form elements in single line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the html elements in my page in a single line.

Demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ulLyUxj9C9PxxvpTnm3N?p=preview

In the demo plunker, when clicked 'Launch the window in separate window' icon on right hand side, a separate window is opened which shows the form elements(not aligned in a single line).
I want the two text elements and the submit buttons to be on the same line, but with the demo code, **submit and reset buttons are not aligned with the
text fields**.
Below is the sample code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <div class=""> 
    <div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" style="width:130px">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:130px">
    </div>     
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't align buttons with horizontal form (not inline) (Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510395/cant-align-buttons-with-horizontal-form-not-inline-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding a class="form-inline" to your row div, like:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="form-inline"> 
<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" style="width:130px">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:130px">
</div>     
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plunkr: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ddVOoneUlEUSM2EO

I did a few things here:

Added the btn class to your buttons so they would have the same height as the text fields.

I added an empty label that only shows at the medium breakpoint or greater to fill out vertical space.

Wrapped buttons in their own div (since labels are inline)

Wrapped the empty label and new div in their own div.form-group.col

```
<div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class=""> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" style="width:130px">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:130px">
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group col">   
          <label class="visible-md visible-lg">&nbsp;</label>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstraps `form-control` class to the two buttons and add some margin between the two buttons to make it looks a bit aesthetic.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary form-control">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary form-control">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just the bootstrap grid class issue.

Make sure You wrap the `col's` ( ie.  `<div class="col-md-2">` ) with the `row` class.

Please see the div structured given below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" style="width:130px">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:130px">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="email">Email:</label></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" style="width:130px"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="pwd">Password:</label></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-10"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:130px"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-10"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button> &nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Reset</button></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it will be more clear after formatting....Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Slightly better after formatting. But... it would still be helpful if you could explain what you did to solve OP's question.

Comment: I just created multiple rows to keep email, password and buttons. And then specified columns in each row. One to keep Label and other to keep Textboxes or buttons